# load iframe before page load

Tags: iframe, popup

My php page took longer to load, I have a popup on click of some content in that page.

When I click the content the iframe in popup needs to be opened in popup, the popup opens instantly, but the iframe within the popup didn't open till the page finishes loading.

And while that time the popup is visible but blank;

How to open the iframe before loading finishes?

My code is something like this:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['u_id']) && $_SESSION['u_id'] > 0) {
?> href="redirect.php; ?>" <?php
} else {
?> href="iframesignin.php?signpopup=<?php
    $encd = 'slr' . $fbanr['s_id'];
    echo base64_encode($encd);
?>&id=<?php
    echo $fbanr['s_id'];
?>&type=slr&mypage=<?php
    echo $fullurl;
?>" data-featherlight="iframe" <?php
}
?> target="_blank"  >
      GO TO STORE</a>
```

Here the popup appears through `data-featherlight="iframe"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use include/require function intead of iframe

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        <iframe src="testing1.php" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you